# SOQL Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: apex, soql

I have a very basic method that correctly returns the value of the Name field of my custom object.  However, when I try to retrieve the value of a custom field I get isnull as the result.  I checked the field level security and I have rights to the custom fields.  If I use the query editor in the Developer Console and run the same query, I get the correct results.

```
@AuraEnabled
global static String getEventName(String eventRecordId)
{
    return [SELECT Event__c.Name FROM Event__c WHERE Id = 'a0M6A000004KFdtUAG' AND NetworkId__c = :netwrkId].Name;   
}

({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getEventName");        
    action.setParams({
        eventRecordId: component.get("v.recordId")
    });        
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var testmk= response.getReturnValue();            
        alert('result is' + testmk);
        component.set("v.eventName", testmk);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

The following query is not working:

```
    @AuraEnabled
global static String getEventName(String eventRecordId)
{
    return [SELECT Subheadline__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = 'a0M6A000004KFdtUAG' AND NetworkId__c = :netwrkId].Name;   
}
```

Comment: What is your query for retrieving the custom field? As of now the query is only to retrieve the name field and seems that's working fine for you.

Comment: Your second query is attempting to return `.Name`, rather than `.Subheadline__c`.

Comment: Are you sure if that's the right query?

Comment: David...although my method name says getEventName, I am trying to get it to work to return the subheadline.  Do you see why it wouldn't return the value in the Subheadline__c field?  Actually...now I see it!! Thank you!

Comment: You should ***never*** use hard-coded ids.

Comment: The hard coded id was for troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify your query to return the field `Subheadline__c` which is being queried:

```
// you need to return the retrieved field here
[SELECT Subheadline__c 
    FROM Event__c 
    WHERE Id = 'a0M6A000004KFdtUAG' AND NetworkId__c = :netwrkId].Subheadline__c;
```

---

Your current query:

```
[SELECT Subheadline__c 
    FROM Event__c 
    WHERE Id = 'a0M6A000004KFdtUAG' AND NetworkId__c = :netwrkId].Name;
```

will not work and will throw a runtime error as below, because you are trying to retrieve `Name` from a SOQL which is not part of the retrieved results.

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field